# How to generate a pem certificate? in an easy way, for testing

Tags: ssl, ssl-certificate, certificate

A third-party app I have requires a *.pem certificate to be able to open a wss connection. How can I generate a *.pem file, keeping in mind that I need that only for testing, therefore I want an easy, not necessarily a really secure way to do so.

I'm on Arch Linux.

Comment: What exactly does that application require from the certificate?

Answer (score 19):

first generate CSR and KEY:

```
openssl req -new -newkey rsa:4096 -nodes -keyout snakeoil.key -out snakeoil.csr
```

then generate PEM and self-sign with KEY:

```
openssl x509 -req -sha256 -days 365 -in snakeoil.csr -signkey snakeoil.key -out snakeoil.pem
```

Comment: the app says "use_private_key_file: no start line" - any idea why?

Comment: it seems your app can a) not find or read the key file (check path/permissions) or b) the key is not starting with "-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----"